# elasticsearch-py: error using async_bulk, index missing from actions

Tags: python, elasticsearch

In its docstring, `elasticsearch.helpers.async_bulk` describes itself as a

> Helper for the :meth:`~elasticsearch.AsyncElasticsearch.bulk` api that provides
> a more human friendly interface - it consumes an iterator of actions and
> sends them to elasticsearch in chunks. [source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/main/elasticsearch/_async/helpers.py#L234)

### Context

I have been using `AsyncElasticsearch.bulk()` successfully to send pandas dataframes to some ES instance

```py
def _rec_to_actions(self, df):
    for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
        yield ('{ "index" : { "_index" : "%s" }}' % (self.index))
        yield (json.dumps(record, default=int))

async def send_to_elasticsearch(self, df: DataFrame):
    logger.info(f"{self.stage_name} sending batch to elastic")
    await self.elastic_client.bulk(self._rec_to_actions(df))
```

### Issue

However, when it comes to `async_bulk`, I am getting `index is missing` errors.

```py
async def send_to_elasticsearch(self, df: DataFrame):
    await async_bulk(self.elastic_client, self._rec_to_actions(df))
```

Tried to tune `_rec_to_actions()` in several ways without much effect.

```py
def _rec_to_actions(self, df):
    for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
        record["index"] = self.index
        yield (json.dumps(record, default=int))
```

I guess the main problem is that I am not quite sure to know **what is an action**, in the context of elasticsearch. This notion is everywhere in the documentation but does not have a clear **data structure** counterpart in this library [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) (none that I could find, anyway)

What is exactly an *action* and how should I tune my generator to send df's data to `self.index`?

**environment**

- python = "3.9.5"
- elasticsearch = "7.14.1"

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers) made it easier:

```py
def _rec_to_actions(self, df):
    for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
       yield {"_index": self.index, "_source": json.dumps(record, default=int)}
```